# How to return data with lucid model with relational

Tags: javascript, node.js, adonis.js

How can I return all data with relation. I try to read adonisjs document can't find anything

Here is my Emp model

```
empImg () {
    return this.hasOne('App/Models/EmpPhoto')
  }
```

I want to get photo in EmpPhoto Model so I add relation hasOne in Emp Models

after That in controller I call

```
 const { id } = params;
 const empData = await Emp.find(id);
 return empData.profileImg().fetch();
```

It's return only data in empPhoto

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "employee_id": 2511,
    "image": "public/images/employee/1111114.jpg",
    "created_at": "2019-03-25 17:48:04",
    "updated_at": "2019-03-26 11:19:31"
}
```

How I return `empData + relation`

Answer (score 0):

TryHard!
You can use  [Eager loading](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.0/relationships#_eagerloading) for your thing like this

```
const { id } = params;
const empData = await Emp
    .query()
    .where('id', id)
    .with('profileImg')
    .fetch();
```